# are there any alternatives to yUML

Tags: open-source, uml, diagram, diagramming, tool-uml

I'm looking for an alternatives to [yUML](http://yuml.me/), preferably open source.
Sure yUML is great and I really like it, but I would like to be able to extend it.

I'm also interested in other services in the same direction (diagram generation), but I'm not looking for any (UML)desktop tools.

Comment: I asked roughly the same question on software-recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26464/tool-for-sketching-overviews-with-ascii-input

Comment: Have a look at this npm project: https://github.com/jaime-olivares/yuml-diagram

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some [suggestions](http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#textual) of textual modeling tools. For instance, take a look at [PlantUML](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 6):

[Scruffy](https://github.com/aivarsk/scruffy) can draw some yUML diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

**[Scruffy-Server](https://github.com/wernight/scruffy-server)** is a newly made web server frontend for **[Scruffy](https://github.com/aivarsk/scruffy)** which has a rendering and syntax almost identical to yUML.

At the moment it doesn't have the PDF/Json/SVG(or PS) export options, but those might be coming. On the other hand it is very fast and has a lean interface.

PS: I might a little be biased as I made it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps take a look at [jsUML2](http://www.jrromero.net/tools/jsUML2).  It doesn't provide a textual syntax for specifying diagram - it provides a js-based api instead.  However the api is very easy to use and it's open source so extensible.  They have a demo app built using it [here](http://www.uco.es/~in1rosaj/tools/jsUML2/editor/index.html).

hth.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I've developed an open source alternative based on Graphviz.

It's basic and only work for relationship diagrams, but it can be extended.

The output look is very similar to yUML.

Here's the link: http://web.fi.uba.ar/~ssantisi/works/glumly/